# Can we stop doing the [samba]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Today an [off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844932/how-to-share-folders-on-a-mounted-partition-on-ubuntu) was [closed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27027008#27027008), and after finding a similar question I ventured into the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samba) & found that *the majority* of questions in the tag are off-topic:

- [How to mount windows share with cifs and access directory down tree where have access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618192/how-to-mount-windows-share-with-cifs-and-access-directory-down-tree-where-have-a)
- [Samba and Iptables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536774/samba-and-iptables)
- [Proper way to configure Samba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401374/proper-way-to-configure-samba)
- [How do I make Samba change ownership when writing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669289/how-do-i-make-samba-change-ownership-when-writing-files)

It however [does seem to have a couple of (questionably) on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823371/how-can-i-get-log-of-samba-delete-file), but even these are of [low-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227332/pysmb-to-get-directory-tree-of-a-smb-share-server).

---

What can we do?

- Burninate- The easiest, but possibly not the best outcome for the rare questions that *are* on-topic;
- Clean-up the tag- Takes the most time, but is the best outcome for the on-topic [samba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samba) questions.
- Clean-up & Improve Wiki- The same as the previous option, **but** to drastically improve the tag wiki (which is copied from the first Google result)

Comment: If there are legitimate questions in the tag, burnination is too broad of an action to take.

Comment: @Makoto I have found only two, and they don't actually *need* to be tagged [tag:samba].

Comment: @bob:  There could be more.  There's a lot of questions in there, sure, but I think that a scalpel is needed more than a flamethrower.

Comment: I still use Samba....<shiver>...

Comment: Of 583 questions in the [tag:samba] tag, [226 are open with a net positive score](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[samba]+closed%3A0+score%3A1), [30 have a score of 5 or more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[samba]+closed%3A0+score%3A5), [at least 11 earned a nice question badge](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[samba]+closed%3A0+score%3A10). That's a lot of open, positively-rated questions for this tag; are on topic questions within it really all that rare? Burnination seems unnecessary.

Comment: It should be cleaned up: there are a *lot* of totally off topic "how do I set up a server"-type questions, but there are also some legitimate programming questions in there.

Comment: Don't burninate, or else there'll be a disco inferno.

Comment: Close vote review queue for Samba: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=samba

Comment: @Canon nice finding. Not intended to be pedantic but just to clarify samba is an entire music style with it own sub categories and culture. Much like blues. Edit: no I mean don't **play** samba =)

Comment: @jean Surely you're not suggesting a migration path to Music or Music Fans, are you? ;-)

Comment: @tepples lol no! But that can be a nice SE April fool's day prank

Comment: Guys, please move to chat...

Comment: **Note: I am *not* requesting burnination here, I am asking what the best action is.**

Comment: This burnination pun is now officially [approved.](http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/red-approved.gif) You may proceed.

Comment: In the case of legit but low volume tags that regularly accumulate crap, the best that can be done is for someone to periodically go through and clean them up.  Downvoting and retagging as needed.  I've adopted one such tag a few years ago, and go in once or twice a year to clean it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `Clean-up & Improve Wiki` whould be the best.

It would be nice if the wiki **explicitely describes** common use-cases, which are **definitely off-topic on SO** and should be asked on other cites. With such description users(like me), who only *partially familiar* with that topic, could *effectively* filter out many of off-topic questions, when encounter them, e.g., in *Close Votes* review queue.

For some `samba`-tagged question I can confidently deduce, that it is concerned only with samba configuration file: it can be explicitely stated in the question itself, or in the accepted answer, or my knowledge is sufficient for make this deduction. **But whether samba configuration is so complex, that it can be treated as programming?** With my knowledge I cannot answer this question definitely, so I cannot take any action except `Skip`. But I *guess* that samba configuration **is not** a programming. If it will be stated in the wiki explicitely, I take appropriate action instead of skipping.

Also, by enumerate definitely off-topic use-cases, we would help askers, who read tag description before using it, to find more appropriate place for ask their question. That effect cannot be achived by simply burning tag.

Comment: IMO Samba is not about programming so questions about it should be closed as off-topic - Super User or Linux or Unix. And the tag should be burninated.